# Current Time in TextBox. in C# visual studio 2010 windows phone

Tags: c#, time, textbox, windows-phone

I have a project of calculator, and i need put on one more thing. textbox with current time in 00:00:00 Format. How can i do this? im using C# VS 2010 for Windows mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the current time.

```
textbox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```